# Photo-electric effect with light reflected from a blue wall

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-optics, photoelectric-effect

Suppose we have a metal which has a work function corresponding to yellow. Obviously, if light with frequency greater than yello is made to fall on it, it would show photo-electric effect.Now, consider a  blue-colored wall. If the metal is kept in front of it, will it show the photo-electric effect? Why or Why not?

I know that the answer is a big NO. But why? I mean...we perceive the color blue when we look at the wall, which may mean that blue light is hitting our retina from the wall.If that is so, why doesn't the metal emit photo-electrons?? 
Also, please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: The answer is a big YES.   The metal will show the photoelectric effect provided that all the air can be removed from the room.

Comment: Why would you think the answer is no?

Comment: I thought NO because I had this gut feeling...if you think YES, can you please answer it? I would be very grateful